# Similarities between bubble sort and selection sort

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I have been looking through different websites and forums but I can't seem to find any post about the similarities between bubble sort and selection sort. Can someone help me plese?

Thanks

Comment: From Wikipedia: [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) almost always outperforms bubble sort and gnome sort.

Comment: There are lots of sorting algorithms, so it's not really surprising that you haven't found a pre-packaged explanation of the similarities between two particular not-very-good algorithms. But what's stopping you from producing such an explanation yourself? If you understand how the two sort algorithms work, it should be fairly straightforward, shouldn't it?

Comment: @DavidRicherby the problem is that I can't really understand selection sort to the point that I can make comparisons yet. That's why I thought that by looking at differences and similarities with bubble sort (which I understand), it could've helped

Comment: Then try to distill your misunderstanding of Selection Sort into a question and ask *that* one. It's impossible for us to know where your confusion lies. Picking similarities between SS and BS at random is unlikely to help.

Comment: Especially when the key point about any algorithm is really how it's _different_ from all the other ones.